# Magento product on load event

Tags: magento

Is there a single event that get fires whenever a product is loaded, either on its own or through as part of a collection?

I need to guarantee that no matter where or when a product model is loaded that i have access to that event in order to tack on an additional object.  Be it frontend or admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::load()` will result in the firing of `catalog_product_load_before` and `catalog_product_load_after`.

`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::load()` will result in the firing of `catalog_product_collection_load_before` and `catalog_product_collection_load_after`.